# Swift4 - Load cookies into WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm trying to load cookies into HTTPCookieStorage.shared so that when I load a URL with `webView.load(request)` the cookies will be transmitted. I'm listening on a flask server and printing `request.cookies` only to have it print an empty dictionary.

Here is my code (`idForWebView` is a cookie):

```
    let myURL = URL(string: "http://10.0.0.1:5000/")!
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = .always
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(idForWebView)

    var request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
    request.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
    webViewMain.load(request)
```

I'm very open to suggestions as to a better method entirely if what I'm doing is utter nonsense! Thank you in advance.